# Google Maps only shows one point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have trouble locating an error on my website [www.ultimize.dk](http://www.ultimize.dk) (scroll to bottom for the map)

Only one point shows up in Firefox while in Internet Explorer it shows all the points. (25 points)

I have been trying to fix it for ages without luck, wheres the error? :-)

Thank you

Comment: first of all there's a png 404 error that appears to be marker's shadow

Comment: That fixed it all, make an answer - it works! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first of all there's a png 404 error that appears to be marker's shadow
```